# How to filter GitHub issue search by linked pull request?

Tags: github

I am trying to participate more in open source projects so I find myself looking at the issues tab a lot. I would like to filter issues but make sure there is no linked pr that would resolve the issue. I find that I click on an issue and find there is already a PR in review. Is there a way to specify that filter?

Comment: This has nothing to do with git (the VCS) and is GitHub specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-for-linked-issues-and-pull-requests):

> **`repo:desktop/desktop is:open -linked:pr`** matches open issues in the `desktop/desktop` repository that are not linked to a pull request by a closing reference.

So, use `-linked:pr` in your search.